# sql left email till @ symbol

Tags: sql, presto

i have a column called Email in my sql database so i need to left my column to get whats before the @ symbol

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: presto database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split_part()`:

```
select split_part(email, '@', 1)
```